# My webView don't work in some type phone(Android)

Tags: java, android, html, webview

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" +
                    "var objs = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); " +
                    "for(var i=0;i<objs.length;i++)  " +
                    "{"
                    + "var img = objs[i];   " +
                    "    img.style.maxWidth = '100%';   " +
                    "}" +
                    "})()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
            super.onScaleChanged(view, oldScale, newScale);
        }
    });

    settings.setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl(xxx.html);
```

Heres my code to load a html with multiple large images and gifs.
The problem some large images in html can't display in Android 5.0(but a few images be loaded).And it display completely in Android 7.0 or Android 4.4.